# Same configuration, junit test work Maven test not

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, junit

I have written a simple junit test case, this is work when i lunch it with **run as: junit test**, but failed when i use the command **clean test** into maven configuration.

MyTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/db-config-test.xml")  
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true,transactionManager="transactionManager")  
public class MyTest{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test  
    @Transactional
    public void getStudent() {  
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Student where id=:studentId"); 
        query.setParameter("studentId", 1250L);
        Student student= (Student) query.uniqueResult();
        assertNotNull(student);  
    }

}
```

db-config-test.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.webapp.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
         <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>              
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
          <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:addressDB"/>        
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>          
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="test" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />     
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>MyTest.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

StackError:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [db-config-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get
>   the default Bean Validation factory
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default
>   Bean Validation factory
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the
>   default ValidatorFactory
>
> Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate
>   Configuration.
>
> Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to
>   load 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL
>   dependencies on the classpath

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences between running tests through the IDE and in Maven:

- In the IDE, dependencies for all maven project are added to one common classpath, while with Maven it's only dependencies referenced in the Maven project that is build that is added to the classpath
- When running a single test, there is no issues with common resources, like static variables. When running multiple tests through Maven, all tests share one "jvm execution", so if you change a static variable in one test, it might break another.
- When using multiple Spring tests with the same `@ContextConfiguration`, the Spring context will be cached and shared amongst the tests. Use `@DirtiesContext` to avoid changes being made that affects other tests.

In your case I'm guessing it's the first bullet point above. Try running `mvn dependency:tree` for your project, and ensure that you have `javax.validation` as part of your dependency tree.